# How to unlink Email from Firebase using Firebase Admin Node JS SDK

Tags: node.js, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I'm trying to unlink Email to the current user that has a Phone Number and Email already linked to it.

here what I do :

```
admin.auth().updateUser("user uid", {
  email: null,  
  password: null,
})
.then(function(userRecord) {
    // See the UserRecord reference doc for the contents of userRecord.
    console.log('Successfully updated user', userRecord.toJSON());       
})
.catch(function(error) {
    console.log('Error removing email:', error); 
});
```

but it was returning error `The email address is improperly formatted.`

for some reason, only when I remove the email this happen, when i do the same for phone its working :

```
admin.auth().updateUser("user uid", { 
  phoneNumber: null,
})
.then(function(userRecord) {
    // See the UserRecord reference doc for the contents of userRecord.
    console.log('Successfully updated user', userRecord.toJSON());       
})
.catch(function(error) {
    console.log('Error removing phone number:', error); 
});
```

The above code works, the phone is removed perfectly. but only when I do this to Email occurring error.

Is there something I miss?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`UpdateRequest#email`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.UpdateRequest#optional-email) must be `undefined` or a valid email. Because you are passing in `null`, this is why you are getting the "The email address is improperly formatted" error message.

Similarly, [`UpdateRequest#password`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.UpdateRequest#optional-password) must be `undefined` or an unhashed password - this will also throw a similar error.

To prevent a user logging in with their email and password, you need to unlink their credential, either on the [server](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.auth.updaterequest.md#updaterequestproviderstounlink) or on the client ([legacy](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.User#unlink), [modern](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth#unlink)):

```js
// admin SDK
admin.auth().updateUser("user uid", {
  providersToUnlink: [ admin.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID ]
})
```

```
// legacy client SDK
firebase.auth().currentUser
  .unlink(firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID);
```

```
// modern client SDK
unlink(getAuth().currentUser, EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID);
```

**Note:** Even though this will prevent a user logging in with an email-password combination, it will not remove the user's email from their profile. This helps to prevent the user creating a fresh account when their old account still exists, if you are using the setting that links any accounts that use the same email.

If you want to remove the user's email address from their profile now that they can't use it, you unfortunately can't just delete the email associated with an account by setting it to `null`. Instead you will need to mask it.

```js
// admin SDK
const userId = "user uid";
admin.auth().updateUser(userId, {
  email: `${userId}@noreply.users.yourapp.com`, // doesn't have to actually exist
  emailVerified: true, // prevents sending verification emails
  providersToUnlink: [ admin.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID ] // throws error if already unlinked
})
```

Comment: what is provider id here in
 firebase.auth().currentUser
  .unlink(firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID)

Comment: @SAURABH It's a constant associated with the email-based authentication methods (password and email link). In Firebase v9+, you import `EmailAuthProvider` from `firebase/auth` and use [`EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.emailauthprovider.md#emailauthproviderprovider_id) (at the time of writing, its value is `"password"`).

Comment: This does not work. Sending undefined doesn't remove the email form the account. There is no way as of today to unlink an email from a user's profile.

Comment: @GauthamPai Reworded the answer for clarity and also covered "removing" the email. The answer was marked correct originally for directing OP to unlink on the client. But as [@pedrobern](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10645790) covered in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72385166/3068190), unlink is possible from the admin SDK too (which I wasn't originally aware of).

Answer (score 2):

You can unlink providers with the **admin sdk** [using the providersToUnlink](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/blob/master/src/auth/auth-config.ts#L187-L190)

```js
await auth.updateUser(user.uid, {
  providersToUnlink: ['password'],
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `email` by re-importing the user.
However, it might remove other properties like `metadata`.

```js
(async () => {
  const uid = "<user uid>";
  const user = await auth.getUser(uid);
  await auth.importUsers([
    {
      uid,
      providerData: user.providerData,
      customClaims: user.customClaims,
      // ... set other properties you need but email
    },
  ]);
})();
```